# Automatically Deploy, Refresh (Clear Cache) and Reload your code for web developers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, html, web

I am looking for something in-line with "ionic serve" which would detect any changes I make on the source code (Source Folders/WebContent) and :

1. Automatically Deploy
2. Automatically Refresh my Browser

So that I need not manually perform deployment -> Right Click my Browser -> Empty cache -> Reload my browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the magic Node module which would save a lot of time and frustration for many developers:

> https://www.npmjs.com/package/reload
>
> Automatically refresh and reload your code in your browser when your
>   code changes. No browser plugins required.

Steps I used to set up:

1. Install "reload" globally - "npm install reload -g" [if you don't have npm/node - search Google there are many tutorials]
2. Place a package.json which starts server & also triggers "reload" to start watching changes on the dev folders [I will place the sample JSON by Monday]
3. Now make some changes to the code file using any IDE (Notepad++/Atom/Eclipse etc) and save the file
4. Simply open the browser and observe that the page which you had already open is automatically refreshing for you **without any browser cache**

*`BTW, this was not that easy to find over search engines !! - Happy Coding`*

Comment: So it's better than ionic serve?! I don't understand why some people unable to reproduce caching issue.. https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-app-scripts/issues/794 I got that many times even though the command appear to work correctly in console

Comment: @Shantanu this is not a replacement or better than Ionic serve.. this is equivalent of Ionic serve for a typical web project (Simple HTML/CSS/JS)